# Query Parse for dates greater than Today

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsdate

I'm trying to query my `Parse` database for all the **dates greater than today's date.**

I will then list those items in a table.

I can't quite get it to work, and also am unsure what format to put the dates in my `Parse` database as.

This is what I've tried:

```
// Date
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Date Today: %@", dateToday);

// Initialize table data
PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
[query whereKey:@"dateTime" greaterThan:dateToday];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```

Parse database:

[image]

Any ideas for what I'm missing or need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your above code is that you are storing your date as a String object, rather than a Date object. This is useless for the comparison query you wish to do.

When using the iOS Parse library, you can pass an NSDate object into a PFQuery.

```
NSDate* now_gmt = [NSDate date]; 

PFQuery *query = [self queryForTable];
[query whereKey:@"dateTime" greaterThan:now_gmt];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
```

You'll want to make sure all your queries and dates are stored in GMT time, which is an exercise left to the reader.

**Saving date as object field**

This should be pretty obvious, but saving to save a date in the first place you would do something like:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:14];
[comps setMonth:2];
[comps setYear:2015];
NSDate* myDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];

PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
testObject[@"test"] = @"Test 1";
testObject[@"testDate"] = myDate;
[testObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
```

Comment: Awesome, I think I understand the first part: store dates in Parse as actual dates (in GMT time), and then use the 4 lines of code you stated for the query.  From "Saving date as object field" down I'm not totally sure what you were getting at, I'm sure I'm just missing it, but what is that part for?  Thanks for the help and the explanations

Comment: @SRMR My second part is just an example of how you save a date in the object in the first place. (Assuming you are creating or modifying the object from your  objective-c code)

Comment: Was I not saving something correctly from what you could tell and thats why you put it, or was it just a type of thing where it was a tip if I happened to need to do it?

Comment: @SRMR This was just a general tip. Not related to your specific code. (The question you posted only asked about querying objects, not saving objects, but I thought I should include this tip, because in the screenshot of your Parse table, it showed you saving your dateTime field as a String, not a Date).

Answer (score 1):

For me, I do not use different date formats storing in database. I put double value in the database. It is easy for comparison.

```
        double d_dateTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

Comment: So you'd say to update all my database dates to a double value, then use the line of code you added instead of `NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];`?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Given that there are plenty of date manipulations you can do with the date objects (especially if you use the moments.js library), I would keep all the dates as Date objects. Otherwise you'll need double <-> Date conversion functions on all your clients, as well as in your cloud code.